# Get all hidden field values when an input field is changed

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" value ="abcnew" id="abc_lkid">
<input type="hidden" value ="abcold" id="abc_lkold">
<span>
<input type="text" id ="abc">
</span>
</div>
```

Need to get the values of the hidden fields within the div where input field with id abc is located and get them only if abc is changed.

EDIT: The value in abc could be changed through js and it could be wonderful if we were able to iterate through the hidden fields within the div than call explicit by id

Comment: @praddy you can check my answer, no matter what id hidden field have and you can iterate through as many hidden fields you have one by one.

Comment: Thanks @rahularyansharma.. Its a pity cant accept more than 1 answer

Comment: No worries and surely Ofir Baruch answer is better than me as he use closest to pick the right div instead of all divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
$("#abc").change( function() {
   alert($("#abc_lkid").val());
   alert($("#abc_lkold").val());
});
```

Or you can iterate over all the hidden fields within the div as @Prady suggested:

```
$("#abc").change( function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find("input[type='hidden']").each(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bypqk/)

Comment: instead giving the id of hidden fields can be iterate over all the hidden fields within the div. Could have more hidden fields

Comment: You're right , will edit my answer and add this option as well

Comment: `var a = new array; a[] = $('#divId input[type=hidden]').val();` would do the trick, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this one?

```
$("#abc").change(function() {
   $('div').find('input:hidden').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
 });
});
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYS/1/)

Comment: I should have been more specific... the value in abc could be changed by javascript

Comment: Ok... let me do some more stuff for that :)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak your edited answer seems copied from my answer, not an issue but not a good practice.

Comment: How can you say that.. i din't see your answer yet... Well it happens.!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#abc").change( function() {
    $('div').find('input[type=hidden]').each(function(index){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/q8FXE/1/)